# Animate images with Javascript more efficiently

Tags: javascript, animation

My website has a simple JS animation. It animates a bunch of photos contained in `#frame1`, and loops then around the screen indefinitely. `#frame1` is actually a 1920x1080 area, which is constantly a rotating photo display.

The memory footprint of this in Chrome keeps growing. It grows pretty quickly at this speed (`50`), and slower at 100. This seems to be because of the large amount of pixels being moved around. Is there any way I can improve the memory performance of this app, without reducing the speed of the interval?

```js
function start_scroll() {
  var elem1 = document.getElementById("frame1");
  var pos1 = 0;                    // Starting position of box1.
  var id = setInterval(frame, 50); // Set speed here.
  function frame() {
    if (pos1 == frameheight * -1) { // If it just disappeared, move it to the bottom and populate it with the next series of pics.
      pos1 = frameheight;
      populate(1);                  // Populate the first frame with the next set of pics.
    } else {                        // Otherwise, keep on moving up.
      pos1--;
      elem1.style.top = pos1 + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `setInterval()` with `requestAnimationFrame()`. This will sync the animation with the monitor update in an efficient matter.

```
function start_scroll() {
    var elem1 = document.getElementById("frame1");

    var pos1 = 0;
    //var id = setInterval(frame, 50); // don't use setInterval
    requestAnimationFrame(frame);      // start once, using rAF
    function frame() {
        if (pos1 == frameheight * -1) {
            pos1 = frameheight;
            populate(1);the next set of pics.
        } else {
            pos1--;
            elem1.style.top = pos1 + 'px';
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(frame);   // loop using rAF

    }
}
```

The animation can be stopped using `cancelAnimationFrame(timeRef)` or a flag.

```
var timeRef;
```

Inside the loop:

```
timeRef = requestAnimationFrame(frame);   // loop using rAF
```

The typical frame-rate would be 60 frames per second. On some high-end monitors perhaps more. You can use the provided time-stamp to regulate this.

```
function loop(timestamp) {
  // compare time here
  requestAnimationFrame(loop); // loop
}
requestAnimationFrame(loop);   // start
```

Answer (score 0):

You cold use `requestAnimationFrame` more or less like so:

```
function start_scroll() {
    var elem1 = document.getElementById("frame1");

    var pos1 = 0; // Starting position of box1.
    var id = setTimeout(frame, 50); // Set speed here.
    function frame() {
        requestAnimationFrame(frame);
        if (pos1 == frameheight * -1) { // If it just disappeared, move it to the bottom and populate it with the next series of pics.
            pos1 = frameheight;
            populate(1); // Populate the first frame with the next set of pics.
        } else { // Otherwise, keep on moving up.
            pos1--;
            elem1.style.top = pos1 + 'px';
        }

    }
}
```

Of course I haven't been able to test that but you could read a comprehensive tut here: http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/